# Constantly changing og meta tags bad for SEO?

Tags: html, seo, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm dealing with a request to change the OG meta tags for pages based on the "status" of an item on that page, which could change every few days. The goal is to have something related to the "current status" show up when a user shares the page such as "X is happening right now!" instead of a normal "This is the page for X.". To do this, it seems we would need to change og:title and og:description dynamically.

Instinctively, I think having these change too often could be bad for SEO but I have yet to find any real proof. I've been looking for any information on the impact of changing these tags too often, but have found nothing. Does anyone have any hard evidence that this would actually hurt SEO or that there would be any other detrimental effect?

Comment: I think it's an interesting idea and would make the social shares more interesting. I've seem Facebook cache og data so you might not be able to get realtime changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meta Title and Description are 2 important factors in SEO.

Changing them every week would not hurt.

What would hurt you, is if the new Title and Description are not related to the content you had previously, this would definitely confuse Google.

Also keep in mind that Google may crawls your website once a week, or even more. Google may miss completely new metas if you change them too often.

Answer (score 1):

Making dynamic meta tag will just only give bad effect for your page . considering that Google update their Database everyday, you will just make it confusing for them .
And also, meta tag is for Search engine not for human . Alternatively, you can make that Status in your page Social media, not on your main Site

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the point of having tags is to let the search engines have an idea what your site is about.

Ranking well in the search engines take time; if the tags keep changing, the search engines won't be able to determine effectively what a page is about. In terms of SEO, that wouldn't help the overall rankings and bringing in traffic.

Comment: Og tags are more for instant information and not indexing data